# NestJS Configuration in a Nrw Nx Monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx, nestjs-config

I've just started using Nx and I'm moving my existing project over to a Monorepo environment.

The problem I have is with the NestJs app. For some reason the configuration file never gets read. I've tried moving it to different locations but I can't find where to put the config file. It doesn't ever seem to get read?

Are configs supported?
Do you have any ideas of where I should put the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the env files directly now.

```js
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
...
environment.settingName
```